# How can I have two languages in the 'baposter' template?

Tags: babel, languages, baposter

I found this [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/baposter-template/fjrfjwqcpyzq) and want to be able to change between two languages .

I used the following commands in the `poster.tex` and `baposter.cls` files, respectively, but I have some strange letters.

**[EDIT by KJO to illustrate problem]** using this class file https://github.com/anriseth/baposter/blob/master/baposter.cls OP gets this unexpected result

[image]

In `poster.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{baposter}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{relsize}        % For \smaller
\usepackage{url}            % For \url
% \usepackage{epstopdf} % Included EPS files automatically converted to PDF to include with pdflatex

%%% Global Settings %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\graphicspath{{pix/}}   % Root directory of the pictures 
% \tracingstats=2           % Enabled LaTeX logging with conditionals

%% My code
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}

%%% Color Definitions %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\definecolor{bordercol}{RGB}{40,40,40}
\definecolor{headercol1}{RGB}{186,215,230}
\definecolor{headercol2}{RGB}{80,80,80}
\definecolor{headerfontcol}{RGB}{0,0,0}
\definecolor{boxcolor}{RGB}{186,215,230}
%%% Utility functions %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%%% Save space in lists. Use this after the opening of the list %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\compresslist}{
   \setlength{\itemsep}{1pt}
   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
   \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
}


%%% Document Start %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


\begin{document}
\typeout{Poster rendering started}

%%% Setting Background Image %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\background{
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \draw (current page.north west)+(-2em,2em) node[anchor=north west]
    {\includegraphics[height=1.1\textheight]{background}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

%%% General Poster Settings %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%% Eye Catcher, Title, Authors and University Images %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{poster}{
      grid=false,
      % Option is left on true though the eyecatcher is not used. The reason is
      % that we have a bit nicer looking title and author formatting in the 
%headercol
% this way
%eyecatcher=false, 
borderColor=bordercol,
headerColorOne=headercol1,
headerColorTwo=headercol2,
headerFontColor=headerfontcol,
% Only simple background color used, no shading, so boxColorTwo isn't necessary
boxColorOne=boxcolor,
headershape=roundedright,
headerfont=\Large\sf\bf,
textborder=rectangle,
background=user,
headerborder=open,
boxshade=plain
}
%%% Eye Cacther %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{
     Eye Catcher, empty if option eyecatcher=false - unused
}
%%% Title %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{\sf\bf
    \gr  Αλγεβρική Θεωρία Γράφων
}
%%% Authors %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
{
      \vspace{1em} {\en Richard O. Legendi, Laszlo Gulyas, George Kampis}\\
      {\en \smaller legendi@inf.elte.hu, lgulyas@colbud.hu, gkampis@colbud.hu}
}
%%% Logo %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 {
% The logos are compressed a bit into a simple box to make them smaller on the result
% (Wasn't able to find any bigger of them.)
\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}
\setlength\fboxrule{0.5pt}
\fbox{
    \begin{minipage}{14em}
        \includegraphics[width=10em,height=4em]{example-image-a}
        \includegraphics[width=4em,height=4em]{example-image-b} \\
        \includegraphics[width=10em,height=4em]{example-image-c}
        \includegraphics[width=4em,height=4em]{example-image}
    \end{minipage}
     }
  }

 \headerbox{\en Problem}{name=problem,column=0,row=0}{\en
  Sampling networks always involves the act of aggregation (e.g., when collecting longitudinal samples of networks). We sutdy how the cumulation window length effects the properties of the aggregated network.
 %%% change to greek language 
 {\gr Αλγεβρική Θεωρία Γράφων}


}


 \end{poster}
 \end{document}
```

Does anyone know what commands I need for this effect and in which file they must be placed?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Please don't post code fragments. Instead edit your question to provide a minimal compilable document that shows what you are doing.

Answer (score -1):

In order to be able to use Greek characters, you should use the inputenc package:

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

Also, the order of languages in the arguments of the babel package is important. The last language must be the primary language of your document.

Comment: Thank you @Marios Hadjiantonis you save my day [new_pdf](https://docdro.id/ggknjz4)